# How long does wubi take?

Tags: wubi

How long does wubi take (not to download) but during the install after the windows reboot? For me it should be a short download (about 10 min) but how long will it take after?

Comment: Less than an hour, or something's wrong.

Comment: A wubi install is just like a normal install and would take approximately the same amount of time as one on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a rather strange question since the answer has too many variables. The "normal" time should be between 5 to 15 minutes. I say normal when I talk about computers with 2GB RAM and a CPU around a Core 2 Duo. Normal in this time of technology. But some variables that will change the time it takes to install (Since the download depends on the connection) are:

- CPU You are using - Slow CPU, slower install. Not much slower, but slow nevertheless.
- Memory you have - This one affects A LOT how long it takes. The less memory, the more it takes. 512MB or more is good.
- Hard Drive - Does not affect as much as CPU or RAM but it affects anyway. If you have like a Quantum Fireball 4GB Hard drive Pata 5400RPM (Like in THIS year!!) then that is going to take more than for example a Hitachi 1TB F3 7200RPM Sata2 64MB Cache + French Fries.
- Motherboard - This puppy is up with how much RAM affects the install. If you have some horrible motherboard (The cheap ones you get in a happy meal) it might look like ages. If you have some pure Intel, Asus, MSI, etc.. motherboard that is known to give power when needed then you are good.
- Installation Unit - Are you using a Pen Drive to install it, an ISO right from the windows Daemon Tools. a CD/DVD from a good or bad/old cd-rom/dvd-rom drive, are you doing it from the network... you get my point. This also affects the speed and overall time.

For cases I had a slow install that took me 35 minutes on a Pentium 3. The fastest was on a Core i7 from a friend who I invited to Linux and that took 3 minutes (I went to the bathroom and when I got back it was done).

Also remember that what options you select in the install. It is not the same to install Ubuntu selecting all 3rd party hardware drivers, packages, etc.., and updates than to not select them at all. Installing ubuntu with everything selected will take a lot of time, not the 35 minutes I mentioned but more than an hour.

So like I said, a lot of variables.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I installed it just recently and it only took around 15 minutes total. It was very fast and ubuntu is great.

Answer (score 1):

It takes about the same amount of time to install as it would to install Ubuntu on its own partition. This obviously depends on the speed of your computer, hard drive and Internet connection.

Wubi just mounts a large file within your Windows partition as its own Ubuntu partition and ensures that the boot loader can remount it every time you boot into Ubuntu. Apart from that, its pretty much the same as a standard install.